# laravel eloquent ignore error when inserting a duplicate key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm fetching a JSON from another service and want to insert a bunch of data in a table. I want to do it a way it won't crash everytime I run it. I'd like to keep my unique constraint on my PK of the table, (cause i dont want to insert the same data twice) but, I don't want laravel to throw a fatal error if it happens (on a specific table only).

How can I insert my datas, and continue to insert if I try to insert another data with a duplicate primary key?

```
Schema::create('dummy', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('id')->unique();

    $table->string('name',100);
});
```

Fetch a bunch of JSON from another API. Then inserting all row:

```
{ 
   'id':1,
    'name': 'one'
},{
    'id':2
    'name':'two'
}
```

that makes.

```
DB::table('dummy')->insert([
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'one'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'two']
]);
```

Then another day, there are new data on the 3rd party API. And want to update my database:

fetch the json, and receives:

```
{ 
   'id':1,
    'name': 'one'
},{
    'id':2
    'name':'two'
},{
    'id':3
    'name':'three'
}
```

that makes :

```
DB::table('dummy')->insert([
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'one'], // <-- will crash there cause PK already existe, but want to keep inserting
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'two'], // <-- skipp cause already exist
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'three'] // insert that line.
]);
```

Comment: You either come up with a custom query that's handling duplicates (like ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE) - for efficiency. Or you wrap the piece of code that's inserting data in your table in a try { ... } catch(\Exception $e) { // something went wrong. }

Comment: @tadman I though it was clear

Comment: It's sort of specific, but it would be crystal clear if you'd included a small snippet of code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @tadman Updated OP

Comment: That lays it out in very precise terms. Nice!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Laravel's Query Builder now has `insertOrIgnore` in version v5.8.33 and up:

```php
<?php
DB::table('users')->insertOrIgnore([
    ['id' => 1, 'email' => 'taylor@example.com'],
    ['id' => 2, 'email' => 'dayle@example.com']
]);
```

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts

---

Please note, `insertOrIgnore` will ignore duplicate records and also may ignore other types of errors depending on the database engine. For example, insertOrIgnore will bypass MySQL's strict mode.

Comment: An this be applied to models with Model:createOrIgnore()?  And before you say use firstOrCreate, it has terrible race condition applicability.

Comment: Thanks you @Jared

Comment: As of Laravel 9, `insertOrIgnore()` does not work and does not ignore any duplicates. The alternative for me was `updateOrCreate()`

Comment: Hi @o4ned -- it's working for me in 9 and 10 -- insert or ignore may not work as expected if there is no unique index against the record.

Answer (score 6):

You may try catching PDO exception

```
try 
{
    // inserting in DB;
}
catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
    // do what you want here with $e->getMessage();
}
```

Alternatively, but not sure, you could try with DB transactions:

```
public function insertInDB()
{
    DB::transaction(function () {
        DB::table(...);
        // if everything is fine, it will commit, else, it will rollback
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

What you want is `INSERT IGNORE` and that question already has been answered, see [INSERT IGNORE using Laravel's Fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622341/insert-ignore-using-laravels-fluent/45151709)