# INSERT IGNORE unique email laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I am using the maatwebsite to import excel to db and

```
$dataArray[] =
     [
         'name' => $row['name']
         'email' => $row['email'],
     ];

Apprentice::insert($dataArray);
```

When the variable is printed the result is:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:18 [▼
    "name" => "Maicol Stiven"
    "email" => "maic1ce@live.com"
  ]
  1 => array:18 [▼
    "name" => "Cristian Camilo"
    "email" => "carin45@gmail.com"
  ]
]
```

the email is a unique, I need when the email is duplicated, omit it and insert the other records

How can I do it? thanks

Comment: I have this same question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/12622341/470749 seems related but outdated.

Comment: I ended up coding this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51431044/470749

Comment: To user insert function for bundle records check there:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622341/insert-ignore-using-laravels-fluent/57037152#57037152

Answer (score 0):

Use the [firstOrNew](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_firstOrNew) method like so

```
$a = Apprentice::firstOrNew(['email' => $row['email']]);
$a->name = $row['name'];
$a->save();
```