# Laravel DB Facade BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to implement `insertOrIgnore` method from the Laravel DB Facade,
here's a link to the docs + explanation snippet:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts

> The insertOrIgnore method will ignore duplicate record errors while
>   inserting records into the database:

```
DB::table('users')->insertOrIgnore([
    ['id' => 1, 'email' => 'taylor@example.com'],
    ['id' => 2, 'email' => 'dayle@example.com']
]);
```

And here's the piece of code that produces the error (it works with regular `insert()`)

```
if ($datetime->format('H:i') >= '05:50' && $datetime->format('H:i') <= '07:10') {
    DB::table('attendanceTable')->insertOrIgnore(['user_id' => $request->loggedUserId, 'day' => $datetime,  'shift_id' => $Shifts->id, 'created_at' => $datetime, 'updated_at' => $datetime]);
```

Here's the error that Laravel's Telescope produces

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insertOrIgnore()
```

Can someone point out what i'm doing wrong, or atleast give me a hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622341/insert-ignore-using-laravels-fluent

follow this link

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @KuldeepMishra Thank you very much!

Comment: @CaddyDZ 5.8, same as the docs.

Comment: In v. 5.8 and 6.0 the grammar for the function is defined only with Postgres, MySql and Sqlite driver, if you use SqlServer should rise an exception `This database engine does not support inserting while ignoring errors` not an `Undefined Method`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error, and it turned out to be because I was on laravel version `5.8.32`, and `insertOrIgnore` was added in version `5.8.33`.

Running `composer update` resolved the issue.